# Parse floats and return paths except for certain attribute values

Tags: python, xml, parsing, attributes

I am trying to parse the floats of a deeply nested XML file and return the paths of this nodes except for certain attribute values. E.g. given the file below, I would like to return all floats but exclude certain attributes say month=05 &  month=06,

```
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="06">141100</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="10">2.304e+0150</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="05">59900</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="08">5.2e-015</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
```

I would like to return `2`, `2.304e+0150`, `5` and `5.2e-015` along with their `paths` i.e. omit texts that are not totally numeric e.g. `english`, `1.21$/kg` or `4.1$/kg`. While also restricting text from attributes `month=05` &  `month=06` i.e. `141100` and `59900`.

From the previous post I have the following which gets the path of all float-able numbers.

```
def extractNumbers(path, node):
    nums = []

    path += '/' + node.tag
    if 'name' in node.keys():
        path += '=' + node.attrib['name']

    try:
        num = float(node.text)
        nums.append( (path, num) )
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass

    for e in list(node):
        nums.extend( extractNumbers(path, e) )

    return nums

tree = ET.parse('jerry.xml')
nums = extractNumbers('', tree.getroot())
print len(nums)
print nums
```

How can I add attribute restriction to this? When i add `node.attrib["month"] in ["05","06"]` to the except function, it doesnot work. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there.

if you add:

```
if 'month' in node.attrib:
    if node.attrib['month'] in ['05', '06']:
        return nums
```

just after the `nums=[]` line it should do exactly what you want.
it's just important you add it before doing `extend`